# jQuery 2.1.0 | Prepending BR tag to button containing text not giving expected results

Tags: jquery, html

Could someone solve this riddle? The following code works swell for links and spans containing text, but not for buttons containing text (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EjduK/14/)). I want to prepend a `<br>` at each odd-numbered button. Currently, only the text within those buttons are affected by the `<br>` tag, but I want the target parent buttons (with their child text nodes) to be affected:

```
$('button').each( function(i) {
if (i % 2 === 0) { $(this).prepend('<br>'); }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `insertBefore`

```
$('button, a').each( function(i) {
   if (i % 2 === 0) { $('<br>').insertBefore(this); }
});
```

Comment: Thx! Time to get my head back into jQuery refresh mode!